# CCSprite spriteWithFile auto size image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am creating a planet with the following code

```
CCSprite *planet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"planet.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
```

The planet itself is far larger than 48x48 so currently the image just clips. I would like the image to auto size into the container.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the container's width is 'width', a number greater than 0:

```
CCSprite *planet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"planet.png"];
planet.scale=width/MAX(planet.contentSize.width,planet.contentSize.height);
```

Although if you are trying to get an icon sized planet (48 points) i suggest you create a texture for that rather than scaling down a very large image ... your mileage may vary on rendering quality when scaling down or up too much.

Comment: Good solution, thanks, I'm just using this solution for testing for now but it is very handy to be able to easily scale this image to any size whilst in testing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scaleTo (or scaleBy) method and scale it according to the percentage difference from the original.